# How to finish all activities in the stack and run new activity with no backstack history?

Tags: android, user-interface

I have the next navigation in my android app:
`login_activity` -> `main_activity` -> `item_details_activity`

`login_activity` is finished after user logs in.
`main_activity` displays items (received from the server). When the user clicks item in `main_activity` ListView new `item_details_activity` is shown but `main_activity` is not finished (in order to let the user press BACK button and return to `main_activity`).

The problem is that session can expire (token received in login) and i have server exception in `item_details_activity`. Then i have to finish all active activities in the stack (`item_details_activity` and `main_activity`) and run `login_activity` with no history.

How can i finish all active activities in the stack?

It's not good idea IMHO to set global `session_expired` flag and check it in all possible active activities in the stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try:

```
Intent in = new Intent(getBaseContext(), HomeActivity.class);
in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(in);
```

Once the activities are out of the stack, they will be removed automatically by android runtime.

Comment: does it mean 'item_details_activity' and 'main_activity' remains previous stack (as new 'login_activity' is started in new task) and are freed by android?

Comment: What's the point of using `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` ? Why not just use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` in current task?

Comment: You can try that as well. @4ntoine

Answer (score 0):

Check session flag in `onResume()` of `main_activity` and if it is `session_expired` then startActivity `login_activity` with `intent.flag_activity_clear_top` flag.

or

You can `startActivity` `login_activity` with `intent.flag_activity_clear_top` in `OnBackpressed()` in  `item_details_activity`

Answer (score 0):

`Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` doesn't work in some cases. The best way is to use a `BroadcastReceiver`. You can register an activity when it starts and unregister it when it destroys. In between if you want to clear all, just broadcast message to clear all registered activities.

Comment: How can the activity receive broadcast when it is in background? The Receiver needs to be unregistered in onPause().

Comment: you can unregister that in onDestroy()

Comment: And register in onCreate?